# Работа с микрофоном на javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, веб-программирование, аудио

Как реализовать такое: голосовой поиск на сайте. Мне надо, чтобы все сказанное в микрофон отображалось в форме и потом можно было выполнить поиск. Все это реализовать на javascript + html + WebAudioApi подскажите, как?
Пример этому google.com.

Comment: если есть пример, то определенно возможно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать Web Speech Api, а именно подмножество SpeechRecognition.

Подробная информация: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API

Пример: https://github.com/mdn/web-speech-api/blob/master/speech-color-changer/script.js (ссылка на демо на главной странице репозитория)